# Computer arithmetic on large integers, (Chinese remainder theorem)

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

When doing a problem on computer arithmetic with large integers, I reached a step when I needed to solve system of congruences. I came up with the following equations: $$x ≡ 65 \pmod{99})\\
       x ≡ 2 \pmod{98}\\
       x ≡ 51 \pmod{97}\\
       x ≡ 10 \pmod{95}$$

I tried to solve using chinese remainder theorem, but it became too large and complex.

The original question is :
Find sum of numbers $123,684$ and $413,456$ by representing the numbers as $4$-tuple by using remainder modulo of pair-wise relatively prime numbers less than $100.$

While solving by chinese remainder theorem the inverse modulo becomes too large.I need to solution to either the  solving of congruences or the full question.

Comment: I would use first some smaller numbers as modulus, maybe 16, 25, 33, 43.

Comment: The modulus you are looking for is a little less than $100^4=10^8$  That is large (but doable if you are determined) for hand calculations but trivial for a computer.  What tools are you using?

Comment: Make the smaller.  $x \equiv 65\equiv 2\pmod 9; x\equiv 65\equiv -1\pmod {11}$ and $x\equiv 0\pmod 2; x\equiv 2\pmod {49}$ and $x\equiv 10\equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ and $x\equiv 10\pmod{19}$.

Answer (score 1):

If I start with $10$ to satisfy the bottom one every time I add $95$ I subtract $2$ in the $\pmod{97}$.  I'm looking for $-46 \pmod {97}$ so have to add $\frac {56}2$ copies of $95$.  The bottom two are solved by $10+28\cdot 95=2670 \pmod {9215}$.  $2670 \equiv 24 \pmod {98}$ while $9215 \equiv 3 \pmod {98}$.  We can add $\frac {198-24}3\cdot 9215=534\ 470$ to get the second line so our solutions are now $537\ 140 \pmod {903\ 070}$  Finally we have to consider the first.  It turns out $537\ 140 \equiv 65 \pmod {99}$ so we are done.  The solutions are $537\ 140 \pmod {89\ 403\ 930}$.  All the computations were done with the iPhone calculator.